# VB.net 1.1 - Is there a Continue For?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, loops, for-loop

Have to maintain an old website using VB.net 1.1 using Notepad :( I have some code that I wrote for a few of our .Net 4 websites that the boss man wants ported to the old sites. Found examples of VB.net 1.1 code that showed use of "Continue For" within a For/Next block to skip to the next iteration. However, when I try it in the code I get an exception that "Name 'Continue' has not been declared." Should this be available, or are the examples incorrect and it is a .Net 2.0 thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Continue` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801hyx6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) was added in VS 2005.

If you really need you could use a [`GoTo` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69whc95c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to jump to the end. I've never needed a `GoTo` myself in 7 years of development in VB.NET with VS 2003.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to remember that Continue For was added to the language in 2005.

Yes a little research leads to this confirmation

```
Continue For
Continue Do
Continue While
```

were added in VB.2005, previously you have only the nasty `GOTO`

Comment: Just seeing it makes me nauseous!

Comment: @HanletEscaño well, the sentiment is mutual, but the OP has only this option or write a very complex and nested if/else.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Me too, I would like to see his code. Perhaps a Goto will not be so bad or everything will be easily reduced to a single if not ----- then. I think it depends on how many Continue should be replaced inside a single for block.

Comment: @Steve, I'm not a huge fan of nesting tons of If blocks, and I'd prefer to break out of the loop with Continue For. However, it sounds like this definitely is not an option. In this case I'll do it instead of using GoTo.

Comment: You're the best person on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the very few situations when GoTo is all right. Look:

```
For count = 1 To 100
   If itsMillerTime Then Goto ContinueFor

   ' More stuff here

  ContinueFor:
Next
```

Semantically identical to Continue For.